# What should a constructor contain?

Tags: java, object-oriented, programming-practices, object-oriented-design, coding-style

What should a constructor contain?

In both cases, all three arguments are needed for the class to work.

Which approach is better and why?

1)

```
class Language {
  LanguageRepository languageRepository;

  Language(LanguageRepository languageRepository) {
    this.languageRepository = languageRepository;
  }

  public void doThat(String firstArg, String secondArg) {  
      languageRepository(firstArg, secondArg);
  }
}
```

2)

```
class LanguageDoThat {
  Language(LanguageRepository languageRepository, String firstArg, String secondArg) {
    languageRepository(firstArg, secondArg)
  }
}
```

3)

```
class Language {
  LanguageRepository languageRepository;
  String firstArg;
  String secondArg;

  Language(LanguageRepository languageRepository, String firstArg, String secondArg) {
    this.languageRepository = languageRepository;
    this.firstArg = firstArg;
    this.secondArg = secondArg;
  }

  public void doThat() {  
      languageRepository(firstArg, secondArg);
  }
}
```

or other?

There are only examples, but in these classes there will be no more methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option seems **1** or **3**, but we need more details about what is the firstArg and secondArg. There are a lot of questions:

1. What is the purpose of the `Language` class? Is a Object? Is a helper class? Is some kind of Service class and the repository can be injected?
2. Who is the first and second arguments? They are fields of `Language`? They will be used by another methods inside the `Language`? Does the repository is used by only one method?

Only looking for what you show to us, the best option is **4**. What is the 4 option?

Look:

```
class Language {
  public void doThat(LanguageRepository repository, String firstArg, String secondArg) {  
      // code
  }
}
```

Why?

- **Your Language class seems a helper class**. You not mention if the firstArgs and secondArgs are fields of `Language`. If they are only passed to be processed for some random method inside `Language`, seems better to have a exclusive method to accept them.
- **None argument is field of Language**. Pass the repository or arguments on constructor would be valid if it will be used by another methods inside the `Language` class. If only one method uses the repository, there is no necessity to put in the constructor.
- **The dependencies of the class and methods are more clear** because only one method needs the `repository` and the arguments.
- **Easier to unit test** because only one method (`doThat`) needs them. If you pass the `repository` and arguments in constructor for only one method use you will be hiding the true dependencies of your class.

Answer (score 3):

From what you asked, your class only seems to be a vehicle for calling `doThat()`. And `doThat()` needs three "parameters", a `languageRepository`, a `firstArg`, and a `secondArg`.

To me, "object-oriented" means that every single instance you have in your application should represent some thing (matching the class name), and I don't see that in your question.

From now on, I have to do some guesswork.

I guess that during the lifetime of your application, you want to call `doThat()` more than once, with individual `firstArg` and `secondArg` values, but with constant `languageRepository` (or or a few enumerated ones).

### Approach 3

Then your approach 3 (setting all three parameters in the constructor) creates a throw-away instance for every single `doThat()` call. Doing this under a class name of `Language` produces Great Astonishment (why should you create a new language for every `doThat()` call - the number of languages in the world is known, limited, and enumerable).

Typical usage would be like:

```
Language lang = new Language(repository, firstArg, secondArg);
lang.doThat();
```

And after that, the `lang` instance becomes garbage - the instance doesn't serve any purpose, and can be replaced by a static method (rarely a good choice).

### Approach 2

With your approach 2, things are even worse:

```
LanguageDoThat lang = new LanguageDoThat(repository, firstArg, secondArg);
```

This becomes useless garbage the very moment you've finished creating the instance. And your user has to learn that here, creating a throw-away instance does actual work - Very Great Astonishment.

### Approach 1

This is the only one that might make sense. You initially create a `Language` with a given (and supposedly constant) `languageRepository` (or a few of them with different, language-specific ones), and call `doThat()` later multiple times with varying `firstArg` and `secondArg` arguments. Then a `Language` instance represents some aspect of language that's relevant for your application (manifest in the `doThat()` method), and survives for more than one `doThat()` call. Usage could be something like:

```
Language lang = Language.getInstance("en"); // or whatever way you choose,
                                            // maybe Songleton Pattern,
                                            // maybe Dependency Injection...
lang.doThat(firstArg, secondArg);
```

### Alternatives

### LanguageRepository

Add the method `doThat()` to the language repository class. Disclaimer: You should decide if it fits there semantically.

### Static method

Make `doThat()` a static method of the Language class, making clear that it's a plain procedural call:

```
public static void doThat(LanguageRepository repo, String arg1, String arg2) {  
    ...
}
```

### Runnable

Implement the Runnable interface for `doThat()`:

```
public class LanguageDoThatRunnable implements Runnable {
    private LanguageRepository repo;
    private String arg1;
    private String arg2;
    public Language(LanguageRepository repo, String arg1, String arg2) {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.arg1 = arg1;
        this.arg2 = arg2;
    }
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}
```

With Runnable, developers are used to create an instance with all parameters needed for execution already in the constructor, and have a no-args run() method do the work. Technically, we're close to your Approach 3, but naming it a Runnable (and implementing that interface) avoids the astonishment. But that might be overkill.

### Advice

Decide what an instance of a class is meant to represent, and then structure follows that.

The constructor should make the instance a valid representation of the concept, and "doing" anything should be the duty of the methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm against 2 because of three important ideas:

1. [It's good to separate use from construction](http://www.netobjectives.net/files/books/esad/essential-skills-separate-use-from-construction.pdf)
2. [A constructor doing real work is a code smell](https://www.google.com/search?q=smell+constructor+does+to+much+work&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS752US752&oq=smell+constructor+does+to+much+work&aqs=chrome..69i57.11183j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
3. [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

1. Mixing construction and use together makes code inflexible and binds knowledge to the same moment in time rather than letting things be decided at different times.
2. If a constructor does real work you've forced the acts of learning your collaborators and exhibiting your behavior to always happen at the same time.
3. Because this:

   new Language(languageRepository, firstArg, secondArg);

looks like a waste of time headed for the garbage collector. It doesn't look it should have done anything besides validate.

```
BinaryMethod.invoke(languageRepository, firstArg, secondArg);
```

That looks like it will do something. Coding is hard enough without creating riddles.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would go for the "construction should yield a valid functional object" approach, so create a constructor that takes  all 3 and maybe other constructors that take less but set valid defaults for the other arguments.

But, you may need to do fancy stuff with object factories that need a default constructor to work. This depends on your language.

In any case, if you were to have constructors that do **not** yield an object in an operational state, you should check in each method and throw an InvalidOperationException or something similar detailing the problem, to make sure the needed properties are set before a method is called.

Answer (score 0):

The 1 **or** 3 approach. The convention is that the constructor creates a blank object that is ready to do work, not an object that immediately begins to work.

Although both will function, after that, it depends on how do you want to use the `doThat` function..